# Filtering the resultset from Mysql

Tags: java, servlets

I have table called user_details with 4 columns (User_id, User_Name, Password and Designation). I have search field in every column where user can give their query and search button will give records based on the query on that particular column. Now I want filter the resultset based on the query from another column. Here is the code for fetching the record from every column

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String query;
    String hiddenname = request.getParameter("hiddenname");
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet res;
    DatabaseConnection dbconn;
    List lst=new ArrayList();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    try {

        if(hiddenname.equals("hidden_uid"))
        {

            String id=request.getParameter("uid");
            System.out.println(id);
            dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
            conn=dbconn.setConnection();

            stmt=conn.createStatement();

            query="select * from user_details where User_id="+id;


            System.out.println(query);
            res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
            System.out.println(res);

            while(res.next())
            {
                lst.add(res.getString("User_id"));
                lst.add(res.getString("User_Name"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Password"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Designation"));

            }

            res.close();
        }
        else if(hiddenname.equals("hidden_pass"))
        {
            String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
            System.out.println(pass);
            dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
            conn=dbconn.setConnection();

            stmt=conn.createStatement();

            query="select * from user_details where Password LIKE '%"+pass+"%'";


            System.out.println(query);
            res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
            System.out.println(res);

            while(res.next())
            {
                lst.add(res.getString("User_id"));
                lst.add(res.getString("User_Name"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Password"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Designation"));

            }

            res.close();
        }

        else if(hiddenname.equals("hidden_uname"))
        {
            String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
            // System.out.println(uname);
            dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
            conn=dbconn.setConnection();

            stmt=conn.createStatement();

            query="select * from user_details where User_Name LIKE '%"+uname+"%'";


            System.out.println(query);
            res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
            //System.out.println(res);

            while(res.next())
            {
                lst.add(res.getString("User_id"));
                lst.add(res.getString("User_Name"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Password"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Designation"));

            }

            res.close();
        }
        else if(hiddenname.equals("hidden_desig"))
        {
            String desig=request.getParameter("desig");
            System.out.println(desig);
            dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();
            conn=dbconn.setConnection();

            stmt=conn.createStatement();

            query="select * from user_details where Designation LIKE '%"+desig+"%'";


            System.out.println(query);
            res=dbconn.getResultSet(query, conn);
            System.out.println(res);

            while(res.next())
            {
                lst.add(res.getString("User_id"));
                lst.add(res.getString("User_Name"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Password"));
                lst.add(res.getString("Designation"));

            }

            res.close();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    finally {
        request.setAttribute("UserData", lst);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayrecord.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        lst.clear();
        out.close();
    }
}

}
```

I don't know how to filter the resultset and display the filtered records. Could any one guide me

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter it by? Do you mean you want to join the tables of two queries?

Comment: How about performing a new query based on the new user criteria?

Comment: @ChristianCederquist I have a single table (User_id, User_Name, Password, Designation). When I want all records which has User_name= "hari", it fetches all the records. Now from this result I want only where the designation="student"

Comment: Why don't you just write:
"select * from user_details where User_name LIKE '%"+uname+"%' AND designation LIKE '%"+desig+"%'"

Comment: @ChristianCederquist Thanks for your reply.  I want user to select the records based upon the result fetched from first search method. As every column of my table has search and field and button for seraching, therfore your code failed as it unable to get the query from the User_Name column.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You mean to say new query based on the result set. Could you give example.

Comment: I mean to build a new query `"select <columns> from <table> where <new condition>"` and execute it again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for idea but I second query should fetch records only from the result set obtained from first query.

Comment: Ok then, since you already have the results stored in a `List`, filter the results in a new `List`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Being a newbie I dont know how to write a query for filtering the list as the query in general are written for SQL table and getting their records. Could you give me a sample

Comment: I just have found your problem is related to web application. You need to use a filter technique in your view. There are several ways to do this, but it will depend on how are you showing the results in your view (JSP or whichever technology you're using).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51501/discussion-between-thileepan-and-luiggi-mendoza)